# Folders required to download when moving a Craft 3 installation to another server?

Tags: craft3

If I'm downloading a Craft 3 website one server in readiness to deploy onto a new server, which folders should I download aside from?:

- /templates
- /web

Also, do I need to redownload the 'cpresources' folder again inside the /web directory if I already have a local copy of Craft CMS installed?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to take:

- /config
- /modules (if there are any custom modules, but no harm in taking it anyway)
- /web
- /storage/rebrand (if you have rebranded the control panel)
- /templates
- /translations (if you have added any [static translations](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/sites.html#static-message-translations))
- /vendor (unless you plan to run `composer install` on the new server)
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- craft (CLI)

You can generally discard the whole contents of `storage` and `cpresources` as they'll get automatically recreated, unless you have put anything in `storage/rebrand`. However, you'll still need a `storage` directory, even if it's empty.